# How do I dynamically add environment variables to zsh prompt?

Tags: bash, shell

EDIT: Original title said "bash prompt", but I use "zsh". I accepted @Artur R. Czechowski's answer because it was correct in a bash context and I was able to make mine work with his help. PROMPT is now `'   ${ENV}${ENV:+ } %F{249}${PWD/#$HOME/~} %{$fg[green]%}'○'  '`, just adding the bit about ENV was all I needed.

ORIGINAL POST: As part of my job, I change environment variables frequently. So frequently that I feel I'm going to inevitably going to forget which one I'm in and do something I shouldn't. In case it's relevant to you answering my question, I change environment by running a shell script and my current bash prompt is `PROMPT='   %F{249}${PWD/#$HOME/~} %{$fg[green]%}'○'  '`.

If I'm in a virtual environment, such as venv, then my prompt gets prefaced with (.venv). How do I get something similar with an environment variable such as `DB_HOST` or whatever variable I want? If `DB_HOST` changes, I want the bash prompt to change right away and persist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is your answer. Example:

```
myprompt() {
    PS1="${DB_HOST}${DB_HOST:+ }\u@\h:\w\$ "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=myprompt
```

It will always display current value of `DB_HOST` variable.

Comment: I added the below to my zsh-theme file, and it turned my bash prompt into a string of characters like this: `\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\[\033[00m\] $`

What I added:
    `myPrompt() {
        PS1="  ${ENV}${ENV:+ } %F{249}${PWD/#$HOME/~} %{$fg[green]%}'○'  "
    }
    
    PROMPT_COMMAND=myPrompt()`

Comment: I am no expert in zsh, sorry. You tagged your question as bash related and I provided you a working solution for that shell.

Comment: You're right, my language was incorrect. I was able to get it to work by adding `${ENV}${ENV:+ }` to my `PROMPT=' blahblah'`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would be good where this should go. .zshrc, some custom script that's called, a theme?